# Pass Search Query to Product Page

Tags: magento2, url, catalogsearch

I'd like to pass the search query to the product page that is clicked on.

The reasoning is because if someone searches for a product, it may be on a grouped product page, so if they click on that result it just takes them to the top of that product page. I can add the anchor tags in the grouped product table, I just need the query passed so the page scrolls to that product.

For example, if someone searches for "Red Cup" and all of my cups are on a grouped product with 50 cups on, when they click the "Red Cup" on the results page it will take them to the top of the cup page. They've then got to scroll down to find "Red Cup" manually rather than the page scrolling to that product

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the answer.

Needed to change the code in:

`app/design/frontend/<VENDOR>/<THEME>/Magento_Catalog/templates/product/list.phtml`

Copy to child theme.

To the link tags for the description and the image hover (depends on theme) I added `<?php if (isset($_GET['q'])) { echo "#" . $_GET['q']; }; ?>`